# What is the best way of working with Services in a VB.NET application?

Tags: c#, vb.net, windows-services, service

I'm using VB 9 (VS2008).

I would like to know how to do the control Windows Services through an Windows Forms application.

I want to know:

1. How to determine the status of a service?
2. How to change the Startup type of the service?
3. How to start, stop, pause and resume a service?

Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

The framework class [ServiceController](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.serviceprocess.servicecontroller.aspx) allows you to do all of these things.

Answer (score 0):

<strike>I'm pretty sure that (unless they changed stuff recently) you'll have to do this either through p/invoke's or through WMI.</strike>

Wow, how did I forget about that class.